# Why background image starts from viewport, not from body origin?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I cant figure out why the background image with no repeating starts from left edge of viewport, and not from left edge of the body element as it expected.

Take a look here

http://jsfiddle.net/pjLs594y/3/

```
<body>
<h1>Акварели зимнего дворца</h1>
<div class="test">Художник срисовал интерьеры по заказу жильцов.</div>
</body>
body {
    background:url('http://artpoisk.info/files/images/9294.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top left;
    max-width:400px;
    outline:1px solid red;
    margin:0 auto;
}
div.test {
    background:url('http://artpoisk.info/files/images/9294.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top left;
    width:200px;
    outline:1px solid green;
}
```

There is DIV with the back image which starts from top left sides of the element as defined.

Comment: Actually what you want?

Comment: "There is an exception to the upward propagation rule in HTML: background styles applied to the body element can be passed to the html element" Thank you.

Comment: @ketan: The title seems pretty self-explanatory.